# Is there a way of removing 'View' from event reports

Tags: civievent, reports, 4.6

Event reports have the word 'View' to the right of the contact name - it's a link to the participant record.  It's not a selectable column in the report and the problem is that when the report is converted to a pdf the word 'View' gets merged into the contact name which can make this unreadable.  Is there any way of removing this 'View' column from event reports? Or making the pdf format better?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug.  In replicating it I saw it was easy to fix, so I did.

See the bug report here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19782

If you don't want to wait for this to be incorporated, you can patch your CiviCRM using the fix here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9546/files

Comment: That's great - thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Just applied it to 4.6 - thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

PR https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9546 has been merged.
Fix will be available in 4.7.16. Thanks for the patch!